# VB.NET Tab complete text box

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that I'm writing, and upon pressing the tab key inside a textbox, I would like it to autocomplete that word from a list that may change at any time. I've taken a bit of a peek around, but I can't find anything useful - most things that I'm finding are about disabling intellisense in Visual Studio - not what I'm after. I need something at runtime.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is rather easy to implement. The question is: what is this program supposed to do if the user presses the TAB key on a portion of a work that matched multiple strings from the autocomplete list?

Comment: @xfx Ideally, it would cycle through the list until the desired one was found.

Comment: @xfx By the way, this would be in the middle of a string. The matches would only ever be one word (not contain a space). On hitting tab, it would autocomplete the word, cycling through possible outcomes. If the last character is a spacebar, ideally, it would cycle through the list again, but this time instead of editing what was previously written, it would add it to the end of the text box, still cycling through - is that possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. In any case try using this sample I created and let me know how close it is to what you 're looking for: [TextBoxAutoCompleteSample](http://xfx.net/ftp/whenimbored/TextBoxAutoCompleteSample.zip)